# Import Error: no module named transaction

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

i'm working in a django project, migrating from 1.5 version to 1.8 version, i have some problems and this is one. When i execute python manage.py runserver, returns me:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py:28: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class LogEntry(models.Model):
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py:28: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class LogEntry(models.Model):
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
octubre 13, 2015 - 08:57:36
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'spid.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

at simple view appears all is working, but when i try to open the url in my browser, i receive this error in the browser:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

and this error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named transaction
[13/Oct/2015 09:03:51] "GET /spid/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named transaction
[13/Oct/2015 09:03:51] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Please show the value of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.py.

Comment: i can't post the entire content, i post it in parts.
`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',`

Comment: `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.threadlocals.ThreadLocals',
     # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'spid.middleware.AutoLogout', 
)`

Comment: If you're upgrading from Django 1.5 to 1.8, you might find it easier to try getting your code to run on 1.6, then 1.7, then 1.8. You should get deprecation warnings for code that you need to change. By skipping straight to 1.8, you miss the deprecation warnings, so your code can break with confusing error messages and no explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [transaction middleware was deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-8) in Django 1.6, and removed in Django 1.8. Remove the following line from your middleware classes.

```
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
```

There is a new feature [`ATOMIC_REQUESTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#atomic-requests) which you can use instead.

For more information, have a look at the section of the docs which explains the [changes to transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#changes-from-django-1-5-and-earlier).

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your answer and your time. I will try it.